# Add a list or vertical tspans in a tree using d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to learn `d3` library and include a list to a tree. Something like:

[image]

#### JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitkandhal/ztgur5gg/)

I don't think I understand the concept of adding data to a node well. Did go through this link: [How selection work in d3?](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [subselection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

```
// keep reference to appended text elements
var someText = nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "properties")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("y", 52)
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// sub-select them with properties array
someText.selectAll('tspan')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.properties || []; // catch situation where child has no properties
    })
    .enter()
    .append('tspan')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr('dy', "0.9em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztgur5gg/16/).

Comment: For newbies (like me), checkout this how it is working https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements